# What is happening when I type ctrl+shift+e, then type and underlined text appears?

Tags: gnome, xorg, accessibility

In Ubuntu 20.04, if I type ctrl+shift+e, then start typing in any app (terminal, browser, whatever), underlined text appears. It could even be in gedit. There are no spaces in what appears, and if I hit escape, the text vanishes.

Here's a GIF:

[image: ctrl+shift+e in action, in gedit]

In the first example, I hit enter when I'm done typing the sentence. In the second line, I hit escape and it all vanishes.

I assume I'm accessing some kind of accessibility feature, but I have no idea what.

In summary: What is ctrl+shift+e doing in Ubuntu?

Comment: I get this too but I get underline 'e' and then it is stuck.  Any key press results in underline e.  It is so annoying as it takes away ctrl+shift+e to get file explore in VS Code.  Have you filed a bug report?